# Homology of inverse limit of categories

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory

In [this](https://sites.math.northwestern.edu/%7Epgoerss/papers/limits.pdf) paper the author gives a way of calculating the homology of inverse limit of spaces in terms of the homology of each space. Theorem B states that under some nice conditions on each space and the Mittag-Leffler property on the homologies, the inverse limit commutes with the homology. There are similar results for groups and group homology. I have somewhat of similar question but for categories. Given an inverse system of categories $C_1\leftarrow C_2\leftarrow \ldots$, let $\text{lim}C_i$ be the limit category. How $H_*(B \text{lim}C_i)$ is compared to $\text{lim}H_*(BC_i)$? Here $B$ is the geometric realization. You can assume that $BC_i$'s are nice enough for example they $H$-spaces. The induced maps on the homologies also satisfy the Mittag-Leffler conditions. If the relation is not so simple, is there some sort of spectral sequence relating them? I want to check whether the map $H_*(B \text{lim}C_i)\rightarrow \text{lim}H_*(BC_i)$ happens to be rationally injective.
Edit: Some simplifying assumptions that you can make. Let's assume the functors between $C_i$'s induce homotopy equivalence and their homologies are concentrated only at one degree let's say degree 0.

Extra Question: Furthermore you can assume that the induced maps on chain complexes are surjective degreewise. I wonder whether in this case you can deduce that the limit and homology commute.

Comment: I don't think that works, because there is an extra issue that geometric realization doesn't commute with inverse limit.

Comment: Sorry I deleted my comment before you responded. I am thinking about when realization commutes with this limit. It should commute with a homotopy limit of categories in the Thomason model structure, but I need to recall things about fibrations.

Comment: @user127776: The geometric realization is irrelevant here, since one could simply use the nerve functor N instead of the geometric realization of the nerve; the homology of the nerve (as a simplicial set) is isomorphic to the homology of the geometric realization of the nerve (as a topological space).

Comment: @ConnorMalin: You can replace B with the nerve functor N, since H_*(BC) is isomorphic to H_*(NC).  The nerve functor is a right adjoint and preserves all limits.

Comment: Since strict limits are used in the main post, are you aware that your question is not invariant under natural equivalences of diagrams C_1 ← C_2 ← ⋯ ?  That is to say, we can replace C_i with D_i using some equivalence of categories C_i → D_i that is natural in i, and the homology of lim_i D_i will not be isomorphic to the homology of lim_i C_i.

Comment: @ Dmitri Pavlov Yes, unfortunately strict limit is making it harder to deal with but I cannot do much about that (That's how the original problem is). According to your comment above, I think it probably implies that the chain complex associated to limit category is the limit of the chain complexes. I think it is known that homology of chain complexes commute with inverse limits but not limits in general. Maybe rational coefficients might be helpful here because dualizing might turn situation from inverse limits to direct limits.

Comment: I don't think homology of chain complexes commutes with inverse limits, unless there's a Mittag-Leffler condition or something. I would look in the Goerss paper you link to, which I'm very interested to read now -- thanks for bringing it up. I'm skeptical about the relevance of rational coefficients -- the inverse limit is inherently infinitary, but dualizing things should only help if everything is finitary... but that is pretty vague on my part. I would only expect dualizing to turn an inverse limit into a direct limit under Mittag-Leffler or connectivity hypotheses.